# Get Index of Num Array in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, indexing

I would need to get the position of an element in may array of type `Array Int Int`. I found the method `elemIndex` or `find` to get the position. My problem is, that I don't need the prefix `Just 5` for example. So how I only get the number `5` in my example?

Comment: What do you want to return if the element is _not_ in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`fromJust`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v%3afromJust) from `Data.Maybe`. Like:

```
fromJust $ elemIndex 2 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And you will get only `1`.

But, this will fail if you don't have desired element in the list and you'll get an exception:

```
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

Comment: Use `fromJust` **only** if you can show that the element you are looking for exists in the list. In any other case, Haskell has fantastic facilities for manipulating things inside a Maybe value – so you can keep the `Just` around until you are sure you can safely drop it and still return a sensible value.

Comment: that will work great for me. the element I am searching for is definitely in the list so I wont get an error message. thank you very much

Comment: Even in this case you should probably use `fromMaybe` that allows you to specify a default case (for Nothing) and put a precise error in there that'll allows you to pinpoint the source of the problem if you were wrong because the default error message won't be much help... So something like `fromMaybe (error "Impossible ! The element should be in the list in this function _fun_") $ elemIndex...`

Answer (score 7):

### The principle

To *safely* extract a value from a `Maybe a` value, you can either use pattern matching, like so:

```
case elemIndex 'C' list of
  Just n -> "You can find C at position " ++ show n
  Nothing -> "There is no C in the list."
```

This will return something like

```
"You can find C at position 2"
```

or

```
"There is no C in the list."
```

depending on whether or not there is a C in the list.

### Making it convenient

Of course, this kind of pattern matching is unwieldy to write all the time, so there exists a function called `maybe` that does pretty much the same thing. If you look at its type signature, you see that

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

So it takes a "default value" of type `b`, and a function from `a` to `b`, and will return a `b`. Whether or not this is the default value depends on whether or not the `Maybe a` value exists or is `Nothing`. For example, if you want to check if a list element is allowed entry into an 18+ club, you can do

```
maybe False (\n -> n >= 18) (elemIndex 'C' list)
```

This will say False if the index is less than 18 *or* if the element doesn't exist in the list. If it does exist, it will check if it's greater or equal to 18, and then return True.

### Keeping the `Just`

What I've told you so far is how to get rid of the `Just` in a safe way. Sometimes, you can't get rid of the `Just` just yet – sometimes you have no sensible value to return *if* you have a `Nothing` on your hands instead of the `Just`. What you can do then is manipulate values when they are still inside the `Just`. For example, to subtract 15 from a value inside a just, you just do

```
fmap (subtract 15) (Just 23)
```

which will return

```
Just 8
```

So you see how `fmap` sort of takes a `Just something` value and applies the function to the `something` part of it, keeping the `Just` outside. If you would do

```
fmap (subtract 15) Nothing
```

it would just keep the `Nothing`, so the result would be

```
Nothing
```

### Making it unsafe (kids, don't try this at home!)

`Maybe` is great because it is an error handling system that forces you to Do Things Right. You just can't ignore the possibility of an error (represented by `Nothing`.) Another common error handling system is terrible with this. That system is the system of exceptions. Nobody will know if you blatantly ignore that an exception can occur, which is a basis for very unsafe programs.

So you really *want* to keep the `Just` until you can toss it away *and at the same time replace a potential `Nothing` value with something sensible*.

If you can *guarantee* that there is *no* possibility of a `Nothing` value. If you *know for sure that everytime you call `elemIndex` the element is going to be somewhere in the list*, then it's okay to use `fromJust`. `fromJust` will blindly try to take a value out of a `Just`, without giving a dang about what happens if there is no `Just` there. `fromJust` will simply explode your program (throw an exception) if something went wrong.

As you understand, you have to use it with much care.

### Being unsafe with style

However, as Jedai points out in a comment, even if you shouldn't be able to get a `Nothing` value, it is better to be explicit about it. Instead of using `fromJust`, consider doing something like

```
fromMaybe (error "The input " ++ show list ++ " shouldn't create a Nothing value!")
  (elemIndex 'C' list)
```

which will blow up with a very specific error message, pinpointing where something must have gone wrong.

This is of course the same thing as the pattern match that looks like

```
case elemIndex 'C' list of
  Just n -> n
  Nothing -> error "The input " ++ show list ++ " shouldn't create a Nothing value!"
```

only compacted into the standard `fromMaybe` function.